# Difference between Auto and Void?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, void-pointers

I am reading the C++ Primer Book (fifth edition) and I have a question upon the book i am reading. It says:

> The type `void*` is a special pointer type that can hold the address of
>   any object. Like any other pointer, a `void*` pointer holds an address,
>   but the type of the object at that address is unknown.

Ok, so I understand that but… I have many contradictions to the statement. First of all, can't you use `auto`? Doesn't it do the same thing as `void`? Meaning aren't

```
void *somePtr;
```

and

```
auto *somePtr;
```

the same?

Second of all it says the type of the attached address is unknown. Can't you use `typeid` to get the type? Like this:

```
int a = 5;
auto *somePtr = 5;
std::cout << typeid(*somePtr).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: `int x; double y; void* p = &x; p = &y;` won't work with `auto*`.

Comment: Why not @TavianBarnes ..?

Comment: Because `auto*` will be deduced to `int*`.

Comment: Oh i see! @TavianBarnes !!! So auto will be converted to the type that holds it the first! Thanks a lot..

Comment: I doubt C++ primer makes a good reading in 2016.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `void*` is **strongly** discouraged in C++...

Comment: Did you compile `auto *somePtr=5;`? I doubt so.

Comment: @SergeyA why not? Its in the top list on C++ Books to read for begginers.. (Coming from a popular question about which books to read...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try running your examples through a compiler? As it happens, neither

```
auto * p;  // error
```

nor

```
int a = 0;
void * p = &a;
std::cout << typeid(*p) << '\n';  // error
```

will compile while both

```
void * p;
```

and

```
int a = 0;
auto * p = &a;
std::cout << typeid(*p) << '\n';
```

are fine.

To give an informal and easy to remember analogy for `void *` and `auto *`, think of `void * p` as telling the compiler

> Don't care about what `p` pointer points to, I'll handle it myself (at run-time).

whereas `auto * p = (expression)` tells the compiler

> Please figure out for me (at compile-time) what (pointer) type `(expression)` evaluates to and make the type of `p` be accordingly.

As a matter of fact, `auto *` is rarely useful. You can simply write `auto` instead and if the initializing expression is a pointer type, the `auto` will be deduced to be a pointer, too.

Comment: Wow! Help me understood more about auto... so basically you can substitute `auto` with `void`... Then why in the world did C++11 Add the `auto` keyword? Also @c650 says that `*void` is a bad practice in C++(As he said in the comments of question). Do you agree? If so why and what should i use instead of `*void` that serves of the same purpose?

Comment: `auto` means: deduce the type from the initializer. `void` means: no type. `auto` is still strongly typed. The difference between `auto` and `auto*` is subtle. `auto*` means a pointer. `auto` means any type and might be a pointer. Similarly `auto&` means reference.

Comment: Yes i know that @jbruni . I stated in my above comment i completely understand that.. But was just curius why C++11 decided to include `auto`.. basically `void` is better than `auto`, cause it dosent have to deduce the type of the initalizer, it is always "no-type"... The only reason i can see there is when the programmer wants the variable he is declaring to be the type its initalized by a type, preety much like `template`! Other than that i see no other benifets of using `auto`, or am i wrong? And also @c650 pointed out that `*void` is **strongly** discouraged. Why?

Comment: `auto` is very useful. Suppose you have a function that returns a complex nested template type such as a vector of vectors. Having to type that is annoying. It's much easier to type `auto a = foo();` than `vector<vector<int>> a = foo();` every time. Plus, if the type of `foo()` changes you don't need to find every consumer of `foo()` and update its type. See the commentary in the C++ Programming Language for other uses, especially in template programming where you might not know the type until the template is instantiated.

Comment: I disagree that `void*` is a bad practice. It's like saying `goto` is always a bad practice. Unreadable code created by artificial rules is by far a worse practice.

Comment: Using `void *` pointers basically disables all benefits the type system gives you meaning you'll have to do everything yourself. (And while doing so, you're likely to shoot yourself into the foot.) Sometimes, this is what you need, but the cases are rare in modern C++. (As they are for `goto`.) But I would stop thinking of `void` and `auto` as related features, it will cause more confusion than good. [`auto` is awesome](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), by the way.

Comment: @jbruni i have never ever done a `vector` of `vectors`! I wouldnt imagine! Is that even possible??? That would be like a matrix i suppose. 5gon im asking why `auto` is awesome. jburni i am reading the C++ Primer because im preety sure thats more subtle for begginers.. And im a begginer(has been 8 days since i started C++).. Anways i will use `auto` for times where i dont exactly know what type a variable will be. I suppose thats the proper usage? Also 5gon, now i have understood that auto and void are completely diffrent topics!

Answer (score 9):

`auto` uses compile-time [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference): the variable has a definite type which is its correct type, however the type is inferred from its value. Throughout the lifetime of the `auto` variable, the compiler will ensure that it is being used in accordance with its actual inferred type

`void*` can indeed hold the address of any object, but as opposed to `auto`, you must explicitly convert the `void*` pointer to a different type before using it. Unlike `auto` that conversion is explicit, and unlike `auto` the compiler cannot warn about improper usage.

Answer (score 2):

*From the compiler's viewpoint*:

- In C++11 `auto` uses the same rules of inference as [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). It basically tells the compiler: *"Deduce the type from the initializer."*
- `void *` tells the compiler: *"Here is a pointer pointing to an object whose type cannot possibly be known at compile time."*

For `auto` the actual type is *deduced at compile time*, so the compiler can warn about possible misuse.

For `void *` the actual type is deduced in code *by the programmer* using a [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to cast to a known pointer type, typically at the point of execution of that segment of code.

---

*From the programmer's viewpoint*:

- Hey compiler I'm too lazy or too clumsy to write the type. I'll just `auto` it and let you figure out the rest. *(And it looks smaller than the type I was about to write. Except for* `int`*.)*
- Hey compiler, don't you dare mess with my `void *`. I'll figure out the type *at runtime* myself (in code...) when I need it.

  - *Useful for runtime polymorphism as the same pointer can be used to point to objects of different types as needed in the context.*
  - Also useful if you are coding a base class and you client needs to store an object of an *User Defined Type* defined by the client.

---

So **NO** `auto` is **NOT** equivalent to `void`. `void` means *nothing*. In fact you can't even declare a variable of type `void`. `void *` however is a *special type of pointer* that can *point to anything!* And `auto *` is redundant, just use plain old `auto` instead.

In your example,

> ```
> int a = 5;
> auto *somePtr = 5;
> std::cout << typeid(*somePtr).name(); << std::endl;
> ```

You assigned an address `5` to `somePtr` which is illegal. Needlessly stating that `*somePtr` is also illegal in that context. Although `auto` is probably deduced to an `int`, which is what you wanted to print.

Well with modern C++ techniques, you rarely see `void *`s and `reinterpret_cast`s or any raw pointers for instance except deep within any library implementation internals.

Comment: Similarly, you cannot do `void&`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question,

void and auto are not same. `When you declare a variable of auto, it means it takes the data types of the value assigned`.

for ex:

auto a = 5    // 'a' is of type integer

auto a = 5.0  // 'a' is of type float etc.,

The actual difference can be observed while dereferencing.

The above statement "the actual difference can be observed while dereferencing" answers your second question.

void* cannot be deferenced, whereas auto* can be deferenced

Answer (score 0):

In case auto variable it will take data type of variable from whom it is getting assgnied. For example
Auto obj =  class_obj. Here data type of class_obj became data type of obj. You  no need explicetly  remember and type cast. In case void * you need to know data type and do type cast explicetly.