# C++11 auto and void* generics

Tags: c++, c++11, void-pointers, auto

Based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895014/difference-between-auto-and-void), can I infer that `int age = 45; auto* page = &age; std::cout << *page;` will allow true generics in c++ whereas `void*` requires knowledge of the type to cast it and grab the value?

I am studying c++ again and thought `auto*` would be a very suitable and ideal replacement for `void*`.

Comment: For the purposes of answering this question, what qualifies as "true generics"?

Comment: @rex I imply that operations including dereference can occur without regard to type.  It is my understanding that generics infers that type is generic, unknown, and not tracked.  It is my opinion that `void*` is pseudo generics at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am studying c++ again and thought `auto*` would be a very suitable and ideal replacement for `void*`.

No, that won't work.

```
int i;
auto* p1 = &i;
double d;
auto* p2 = &d;

p1 = p2; // Won't work.
```

Even though `p1` and `p2` are declared using the `auto` keyword, the types of those objects are different. They are `int*` and `double*`, respectively.

Had we used

```
void* p1 = &i;
void* p2 = &d;
```

The following would be OK.

```
p1 = p2;
```

Support for generics is not provided at the core language level. You'll have to use [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html) to get support for generics.

Comment: Good point; then why does auto imply generics hype if it can be assigned a type but then must remain with that type during its' lifetime?

Comment: @Mushy, `auto` simply means *auto-matically deduce the type*. I am not sure who is creating the hype that you talking about.

Comment: Reading Stroustrups' c++ book I get the notion that auto's best use is avoiding long type name but one still has to know what type is being used with `auto` much like `void*` so I see no generic advantage to either of them.

Answer (score 1):

`auto foo = GetFoo();` is not meant to be a replacement for `void*`. An `auto`'ed variable has a very specific, compile time determined type. The `auto` keyword is meant to say the compiler "Please, infer the object type for me". Indeed, you cannot just declare an `auto` variable. You must assign it, so that the compiler can know what type it actually is)

This is useful especially for templated types, which can have a cumbersome, lenghty and ugly syntax but definitely not for generic programming.

BTW `auto*` does not really add anything wrt plain `auto`. In each case, the type is given by the expression right hand side.

```
auto* foo = nullptr;   // compile error: cannot determine type
void* vFoo = nullptr;  // OK, void* type variable
int bar = 5;           // declares int variable
auto pBar = &bar;      // compile-time determined type: int*
auto* pBar2 = &bar;    // same as pBar
vFoo = &bar;           // OK
double otherBar = 5.0; // declares double variable
pBar = &otherBar;      // compile error: wrong type
```

Answer (score 1):

There are useful application of `void*` It discard every type information and let you play with memory. Whereas `auto` is inferring type information at compile time.

For example, you can have a vector of `void*`:

```
// please don't do that unless you have good reason.
std::vector<void*> vars;

vars.push_back(new int);
vars.push_back(new double);
```

But this won't work with `auto`, as it must be inferred at compile time. And even if it's inferred, the container will contains all the same types:

```
// An old concept syntax, rejected

std::vector<auto*> vars = std::vector<int*>{};

vars.push_back(new int);
vars.push_back(new double); // error! double* is not int*!
```

`auto` is all compile time. `void*` drops all compile time knowledge. So `auto` is not a replacement of `void*`, but quite the contrary.